# How to do live editing on Java (JSF) XHTML files on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets

It's been a while since I've worked in the Java world.

I have a WAR file that I need to edit and repackage for the server. It's a Boostrap UI (2.3) web project with some XHTML files. I started downloading Tomcat and Eclipse, but it's a bit confusing to setup.

Is there a straight forward way for me to work on these files so that I can edit the XHTML/CSS, hit "save," and see my changes in the browser? Thanks.

Comment: The answer to the last sentence in your question is: "Yes". And regarding the 'how' you'd most likely ask next, the answer is: "The same as on Windows ans d Linux". Wjich makes me wonder how you did all this "a while ago"...

Comment: Why do you have a WAR file? Where is the Source Code?